# Is PostGIS geography type EPSG:4326 only?

Tags: postgis, geography-data-type

I was under the impression that the geography type only uses the lat,long based coordinates `EPSG:4326`. And I didn't remember having to specify a CRS for a `geography` column.

However, from this [boundless example](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html):

```
SELECT * FROM geography_columns;

          f_table_name    | f_geography_column | srid |   type
--------------------------+--------------------+------+----------
 nyc_subway_stations_geog | geog               |    0 | Geometry
 airports                 | geog               | 4326 | Point
```

It can have other `SRID`s such as `0` as shown above.

Does `geography` type use `4326` only?

Comment: A SRID of 0 is also assigned when you don't specifically assign one. I recall a debate among the Postgis developers as to whether a missing SRID should be reported as -1 or 0. I was in favour of -1, 0 was chosen. If you look at the definition of the geometry_columns view you will discover a function, typemod_get_srid, which appears to be the culprit, [see](http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.2/da/de7/liblwgeom_8h_source.html#l00149) ` #define TYPMOD_SET_SRID(typmod, srid) ((typmod) = (((typmod) & 0xE00000FF) | ((srid & 0x001FFFFF)<<8)))
`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [PostGIS website](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html), `4326` used to be the only supported CRS for geography types, but not any more:

> Prior to PostGIS 2.2, the geography type only supported WGS 84 long
>   lat (SRID:4326). For PostGIS 2.2 and above, any long/lat based spatial
>   reference system defined in the spatial_ref_sys table can be used. You
>   can even add your own custom spheroidal spatial refence system as
>   described in geography type is not limited to earth.

Answer (score 5):

While what [laser](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/99977/laser) says is true, I believe the reason for the SRID appearing as 0 is due to a decision made by Postgis developers that an undefined SRID should be reported as 0 -- there was a debate, in which -1 was also suggested. (I know this because I took part in said debate on IRC, and favoured -1, as it think it is more obviously undefined than 0).

If you look at the definition of the geography_columns view,

```
\df+ geography_columns

SELECT current_database() AS f_table_catalog,
  n.nspname AS f_table_schema,
  c.relname AS f_table_name,
  a.attname AS f_geography_column,
  postgis_typmod_dims(a.atttypmod) AS coord_dimension,
  postgis_typmod_srid(a.atttypmod) AS srid,
  postgis_typmod_type(a.atttypmod) AS type
FROM pg_class c,
  pg_attribute a,
  pg_type t,
  pg_namespace n
WHERE t.typname = 'geography'::name AND a.attisdropped = false AND a.atttypid = t.oid AND a.attrelid = c.oid AND c.relnamespace = n.oid AND NOT pg_is_other_temp_schema(c.relnamespace) AND has_table_privilege(c.oid, 'SELECT'::text);
```

you will see a refence to a function postgis_typmod_srid. Following that rabbit hole, you will find the [function defined here](http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.2/da/de7/liblwgeom_8h_source.html#l00149) as:

```
#define TYPMOD_SET_SRID(typmod, srid) ((typmod) = (((typmod) & 0xE00000FF) | ((srid & 0x001FFFFF)<<8))).
```

It is easy enough to confirm this by creating a geography column and then looking at geography_columns. Given that you could also create a geometry column with any custom spheroid, it seems a bit pointless to allow this functionality in the geography type, given the prevalence of WGS84.

`